# How do I call a function from another contract using Chainlink Automation

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

I am trying to call a function from another contract using the Chainlink Automation `performUpkeep` function. The function I am specfically trying to call is `assertTruth` from UMA's OptimisticOracleV3. Unfortunatley I am having no luck.

I have tried putting the function call in the `performUpkeep` and also tried using `delegatecall`. Both did not work.

Comment: It may be useful for you to share your code?  Hard to diagnose without.  inside performUpkeep are you doing something like 

`OptimisticOracleV3.[FunctionName]()`?